# add foreign key fields to form

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to create a form from this model:

```
class A(models.Model):
    u = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

and then create this form:

```
class AForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = ['u']
```

then i create an instance of that form in my view and send it to my template as a context I'll get a drop down list to choose from existing users but what i want to do is to have a text field to change my current user's first name or last name.
I'll be grateful if you could help me to change my form class to get the right result.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the first and last name fields to the `AForm` ModelForm in the following way:

```
class AForm(ModelForm):
  first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
  last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)

  class Meta:
    Model = A

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(AForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['first_name'].initial = self.instance.u.first_name
    self.fields['last_name'].initial = self.instance.u.last_name

  def save(self, commit=True):
    self.instance.u.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
    self.instance.u.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
    self.instance.u.save()
    return super(AForm, self).save(commit=commit)
```

Comment: can i use the same method for changing current password?

Comment: Assuming you're using Django's User model, then not exactly. Look into Django's `AdminPasswordChangeForm` code to see how a user's password change should be handled.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you do not need a modelform of `A` but a modelform of `User`. You would need to set the form's instance appropriately in the view. For example,

```
a_record = A.objects.get_object_or_404(A, id=1)
form = self.UserForm(instance=a.u)  # UserForm is a modelform of User
```

Comment: it is not answer :) post it as comment

Comment: What are you talking about? Why is this not an answer? How would this fit into a comment? Does this not deal with the issue? If you feel like you can address the OP's issue better, feel free to post your own answer.

Comment: look at @OrenD "answer"

Comment: Both answers solve the issue. If you disagree with this you have to provide some constructive argument. OrenD's answer is more pythonic. Mine is more consise.